# "Madman with cat cannon" mentioned in the Daily Show

Tags: character, the-daily-show

I recently heard Trevor Noah of the Daily Show say:

> Not to be confused with the D.C. Madman, the eccentric 19th century scientist known for attacking the White House with a cat-cannon

Who exactly is he referring to? I thought this might be a comics character, so I posed this question on scifi.SE, but the folks there assured me it's not.

Comment: Noah should get his facts checked: [It was a *dog*, a *20th century* scientist and he attacked the people who broke *into* his house, which just happens to be white.](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/70/23/19/7023199f01830528170a1d93fd27577f.jpg) (And all kidding aside: 1. This simply seems like a *made up joke*; 2. Please don't crosspost questions on SE. [There are alternatives.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu))

Comment: Thank @Walt for the clue, and for letting me know about cross posting. I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 2):

1. It was a joke.
2. The joke involves a fictional attack on the White House.
3. The White House is in Washington, D.C.
4. The fictional attacker is known as the D.C. Madman because he's insane and he is famous because of his cat-cannon-and-Presidential-mansion-related actions in Washington, D.C.
5. This isn't a real story, or a real character, except insofar as Trevor Noah told a story about said character, in the form of the aforementioned joke.